# Is there a hash algorithm that secure enough to hash passwords without a salt?

Tags: security, encryption, cryptography

For example, is SHA-1 secure enough to verify user passwords without salt?

Or do we always need a salt to prevent attacks?

Comment: Assuming you use a perfectly designed 10000 bit hash and two users happen to use the same password that you hash without salt...
Dictionary attacks are easier to conduct on unsalted passwords.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not directly about programming, try security.stackexchange.com

Comment: side-note, don't use SHA1, NIST disencourges it, use a stronger SHA or HMAC

Comment: @SirGalahad Or neither of those.  Because a single iteration of any hash/HMAC is not enough for password storage.  Use bcrypt or PBKDF2.

Comment: @LukePark well, for general hashing purpose, don't use MD5 or SHA1, password is an entirely different story

Answer (score 9, accepted):

General consensus would be that salt should be used regardless of hash function, its easy to do, and makes attacks orders of magnitude harder. Modern security best practice encourages assuming that any part of your infrastructure could be (or already is) breached, requiring that all other components of your system be hardened to limit the damage such an attacker could do.

Salting passwords largely prevents rainbow table attacks.

A rainbow table is a list of possible passwords (either enumerated from possible combinations of characters, or built from a dictionary) that are run through a hash and the password stored with its resulting hash.

An attacker using a rainbow table would compare a hash recovered from their target, with their precomputed list, to find a password that results in the matching hash.

Pre-computed rainbow tables are freely available. http://project-rainbowcrack.com/table.htm for eg. provides SHA1 tables for all 1-8 digit passwords using upper and lower case alphabets, numbers, and common symbols, or 1-9 digits for alphanumeric combinations.

If sites did not use salt, passwords for all users with passwords 8-9 characters or less would exist in these tables, and could be trivially reversed should an attacker gain access to a sites password database.

Adding salt increases the complexity of the data entering the hash function, vastly increasing the pre-computation work required to build useful rainbow tables.

SHA1 alone is not an ideal algorithm for hashing passwords, hash functions [by design are fast](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/16354/whats-the-advantage-of-using-pbkdf2-vs-sha256-to-generate-an-aes-encryption-key), making them useful for generating indexes for example. This also makes them efficient for generating rainbow tables. Multiple rounds of hashing are often used to make this harder (for eg. hashing the password, and repeatedly hashing the result 1000 times). There are existing standards for deriving keys for use in storing password, such as [PBKDF2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2).

Finally, I would consider building your own mechanisms for securing user credentials as an **absolute last resort**. Most languages have pre existing libraries that implement good robust reliable solutions.

[This](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm) article covers the topic well.

Comment: This is a very good answer. The bottom line is that for storing passwords, PBKDF2 (or Bcrypt) should be used and not plain hashes like sha2 which is not considered secure anymore for this purpose, even with a salt.